# Overwrite paste whole row if copied row's first column value matches

Tags: vba, excel

I have list of ship data in sheet2. First column is ship's name and the others columns are that ship's details. A row below is another ship and so on. What I'm trying to do is copy a row of ship data in sheet1 and paste it to sheet2, but if sheet2 already has that ship i want that ship in sheet2's row replaced with copied one from sheet1.

What I got so far is I copy the row from sheet1 and paste it to sheet2's first avaible empty row and then sort it in alphabetical order :P. So I have lots of rows with the same ship.

Here is my code:

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim copySheet As Worksheet
Dim pasteSheet As Worksheet

Set copySheet = Worksheets("sheet1")
Set pasteSheet = Worksheets("sheet2")

copySheet.Range("A5:AT5").Copy

pasteSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial     xlPasteValues

Application.CutCopyMode = False

Worksheets("sheet2").Activate

Sheets("sheet2").Range("A2").CurrentRegion.Select

Selection.Sort Key1:=Sheets("sheet2").Range("A1"), Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes, _
    OrderCustom:=1, MatchCase:=False, Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, _
    DataOption1:=xlSortNormal

Set Rng = Nothing


Application.CutCopyMode = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Do you want to loop down through all ships listed in sheet1?

Comment: No, there will be always one listed ship in sheet1 in a specified row

Comment: done (please see below)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here:

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim Rng As Range

Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A5:AT5").Copy   ' copies the row mentioned

Sheets("Sheet2").Activate
Set Rng = Range("A:A").Find(What:=Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A5").Value, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=True) ' Check to see if ship is already in sheet2 ("Rng = nothing" means it's not, "Rng = [Ship's name]" means it is)

If Not Rng Is Nothing Then  'if it's not nothing, it's somthing (ship's name)
    Rng.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False 'Pastes over old record of ship
    Else
        Range("A" & Range("A" & Cells.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False ' enters ne entry for ship
End If

Application.CutCopyMode = False

Sheets("sheet2").Range("A2").Sort Key1:=Sheets("sheet2").Range("A1"), Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes, OrderCustom:=1, MatchCase:=False, Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, DataOption1:=xlSortNormal

Set Rng = Nothing

Application.CutCopyMode = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I have modified your code and added a part to find the ship in sheet1 (A5) in sheet2. If found, code will replace the data else add to the end of the data.

```
Sub CopyShip()

Dim copySheet As Worksheet
Dim pasteSheet As Worksheet

Set copySheet = Worksheets("sheet1")
Set pasteSheet = Worksheets("sheet2")

Dim rowToCopy As Integer
rowToCopy = 5 ' this variable in case a for loop is implemented in future

Dim findShip As Range

'find current ship in sheet2
Set findShip = pasteSheet.Cells.Find(What:=copySheet.Range("A" & rowToCopy), LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
        LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
        MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)


copySheet.Range("A" & rowToCopy & ":AT" & rowToCopy).Copy
If findShip Is Nothing Then
    'current ship was not found
    pasteSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    Else
    'ship with same name was found
    'assuming all data is within columns A to AT
    'other wise need to clear the entire row before pasting
    pasteSheet.Cells(findShip.Row, 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
End If


Application.CutCopyMode = False
Worksheets("sheet2").Activate
Sheets("sheet2").Range("A2").CurrentRegion.Select
Selection.Sort Key1:=Sheets("sheet2").Range("A1"), Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes, _
    OrderCustom:=1, MatchCase:=False, Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, _
    DataOption1:=xlSortNormal

End Sub
```

Comment: I don't know There wasnt any error but this didn't work, thank you for your time anyway.